# Is it possible to mount windows drive in Ubuntu and make it writeable?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, cifs

Running Ubuntu 12.04. I have Windows Server running in VBox... I can mount the Windows drive just fine, but no matter what I try I can't get it mount writeable.

The latest attempt looks something like this...

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user,rw,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD //192.168.1.20/websites /media/websites
```

The mount works just fine, but everything is readonly.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [Mount your widows Partitions and make it read/writable in ubuntu](http://www.debianadmin.com/mount-your-widows-partitions-and-make-it-readwritable-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. It is not possible to mount a windows files system from a VBox vm in Ubuntu 12.04 (with write privileges).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try to give the file privileges
I mean  `sudo chmod +x "File name or path to it"`

Comment: Actually, I just tried that again and got a 'Permission denied' (running chmod as sudo, mind you) - There MUST be a way to do this... am I the only one that needs to mount a windows drive and can't?

Comment: try other way <code> sudo su </code> and then chmod without sudo at beggining

Answer (score -1):

Hi YES its possible mount windows folders in vbox ubuntu 12.04 as full access, if you declare the folders in virtualbox as permanent and automount then a folder is created in /media/sf_FOLDER , to make it writeable you need to umount then change permissions to the folder and then mount again, and now is writeable.

Comment: That creates a share in Ubuntu that is accessible in Windows. I need a share in Windows that is accessible from Ubuntu.